# Can I define the = operator for my class in Scala

Tags: scala, operator-keyword, assign

I know that one can define an operator in Scala like this :

```
class value(var valu:Int) {
  def +(i:Int) = { this.valu + i }
  def ==>(i:Int ) = { this.valu = i }
}
```

But I cannot seem to overload the = operator like this :

```
class value(var valu:Int) {
  def =(i:Int) = { this.valu = i }
}
```

Do you know if there is any way to do this?

Comment: You would need to implement `update` - see: http://otfried.org/scala/apply.html

Comment: Scala is not C++. Variable name holds a reference, and `=` is reserved for assigning the reference to an object. The closest you can get is using `update` like @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez suggested, and do like `valueObject() = 100` (it is a syntax sugar in Scala that you can omit `update` method name)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for making mutable objects isn't obvious and isn't encountered often because mutability is generally undesirable.

```
class Value(private var valu:Int) {
  def update(i:Int) :Unit = valu = i
}

val v = new Value(19)
v() = 52
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know if there is a way to achieve without using the v() notation ?

Comment: No, I don't. As @som-snytt has pointed out, `=` is a reserved word, not a method, and thus cannot be overridden in the standard manner.

Answer (score 2):

`=` is a reserved word like `yield`, so to use it as an identifier, you put it in backticks, though I suspect no one does that:

```
scala> class C(var i: Int) { def `=`(n: Int) = i = n }
defined class C

scala> val c = new C(42)
c: C = C@9efcd90

scala> c.`=`(27)

scala> c.i
res1: Int = 27

scala> c `=` 5

scala> c.i
res3: Int = 5
```

Compare:

```
scala> val yield = 2
           ^
       error: illegal start of simple pattern

scala> val `yield` = 2
yield: Int = 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a away to do this like in c++ but it seems one just can't override " = ".